# Dynamics NAV - Open vendor items as per date

Tags: sql, accounting, dynamics-nav

For reconciliation purpose I need a table showing all open vendor items as per a specified date. The list of open vendor posts must sum to the customer balance.

I have created a simple query as shown below. The query works when closing the posts normally with a payment, refund etc. My problem is how to handle invoices closed with a creditnote and off course the opposite.

I'm not a SQL expert and don't have access to the source code i Dynamics NAV.

When closing a vendor post "normally" there is one line in the Vendor Ledger Entry table and one line in the Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry. I'm using the posting date, closing date, closed by amount and closing date to calculate the remaining amount as per the specified date.
When an invoice is closed using a creditnota there is two lines in the detailed table and still only one in the vendor entry table. When looking at both the invoice and creditnote I can see that only one of the posts holds the closing date and closing amount. Because of this I believe that I need to ignore these informations.

I believe that I can solve the problem by first summing up the Amount and Group by `Vendor Ledger Entry No_`. When the sum equals `0` I can ignore closing date and closing amount. Only after this I can use my current query.

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Can I attach a simple table example visualising my data?

-- **QUERY**--

```
SELECT *

-Case WHEN VLE.[Closed at Date] <= '2016-06-30' THEN DVLE.[Amount (LCY)]-VLE.[Closed by Amount (LCY)]
WHEN VLE.[Closed at Date] > '2016-06-30' THEN DVLE.[Amount (LCY)]
END as Beløb

FROM [Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry] as DVLE
JOIN [Vendor Ledger Entry] as VLE ON DVLE.[Vendor Ledger Entry No_] = VLE.[Entry No_]

WHERE DVLE.[Posting Date] between '2015-01-04' and '2016-06-30' and
DVLE.[Document Type] >= 2 and

Case WHEN VLE.[Closed at Date] <= '2016-06-30' THEN -DVLE.[Amount (LCY)]+VLE.[Closed by Amount (LCY)]

WHEN VLE.[Closed at Date] > '2016-06-30' THEN -DVLE.[Amount (LCY)]
END <> 0
```

Comment: Could you post screenshots of both examples from Nav? The "normal" and with credit memo. Because in normal case there should also be more than one detailed entry. Firts detailed entry is initial sale entry (-amount) and then applied entry (+amount). The sum of those entries gives you remaining amount.

Comment: I have now looked into the tables again and see that I can get the result by summing posts in the Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry. As you tell this table holds alle the needed transactions. Thank you for your reply as it kicked me back in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my issue with this query:**

```
SELECT *

FROM [Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry] as DVLE
JOIN [Vendor Ledger Entry] as VLE 
ON DVLE.[Vendor Ledger Entry No_] = VLE.[Entry No_]

WHERE DVLE.[Posting Date] <= '2016-06-30' 

GROUP BY VLE.[Posting Date] ,
VLE.[Vendor No_] ,
VLE.[Global Dimension 1 Code] ,
VLE.[Due Date] ,
VLE.[Closed at Date] ,
VLE.[External Document No_] , DVLE.[Vendor Ledger Entry No_]

HAVING sum(DVLE.[Amount (LCY)]) <> 0
```